# How can make a list from matrix in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**I have an array like this**

```
  const input_array= [
    ["black", "blue"],
    ["large", "medium"],
    ["a", "b", "c"]
    //... is it dynamic can be added many rows
  ];
```

**How would I get an array like this :**

```
const finallist = [
    ["black", "large", "a"],
    ["black", "large", "b"],
    ["black", "large", "c"],
      
    ["black", "medium", "a"],
    ["black", "medium", "b"],
    ["black", "medium", "c"],

    ["blue", "large", "a"],
    ["blue", "large", "b"],
    ["blue", "large", "c"],
      
    ["blue", "medium", "a"],
    ["blue", "medium", "b"],
    ["blue", "medium", "c"],
  ]
```

**Please Remember input_array is dynamic**

**Please advice me how can I do this**

Comment: You could do this recursively? But depending on how many top level items there are you could reach a stack limit.

Comment: can you give me an example code?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this, might be helpful:

```js
const input_array = [
    ["black", "blue"],
    ["large", "medium"],
    ["a", "b", "c"]
    //... is it dynamic can be added many rows
];
const mmc = input_array.reduce((e, r) => e * r.length, 1);
const finallist = input_array.map((x,i)=>({index:i,arr:x})).reduce((e, r) => {
    for (var u = 0; u < mmc; u++) e[u] && (!r.arr.some(r => e[u].includes(r)) || e[u].length <= r.index) ? e[u].push(r.arr[u % r.arr.length]) : e.push([r.arr[u % r.arr.length]]);
    return e.sort(), e
}, []);
```

**Careful!** This might break your browser in large matrix scales.

Comment: Hi @SarwarHasan. Sorry for a mistake I've made. There lives a bug! The code above may result wrong if there is duplicated values in two different matrix; Therefore, I've killed the bug editing my answer so that it would give correct answer under mentioned conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const input_array = [
    ["black", "blue"],
    ["large", "medium"],
    ["a", "b", "c"]
]
const getCompinations = array =>
  array.reduce((v, b) =>
    v.reduce((r, g) => [...r, ...b.map(w => [].concat(g, w))], [])
  )
console.log(getCompinations(input_array))
```